# UNetBootin and Partition Wizard

Tags: boot, usb, iso

I'm trying to burn ISO to my 4GB Usb drive because i set boot partition as active I can't find this option in GParted. I have set in BIOS to boot up from usb but it says `No Operating System Found` when i boot from usb. Please help.

Comment: Is it NTFS? try format it as FAT32 first before using UNetBootin!

Comment: No its FAT32 formated before doing it. Im now on chrome Os installed on pendrive so im sure that BIOS settings are fine. When i burned it 2nd time flag was set to boot. But im too lazy to check if it works now :P

Answer (score 0):

The must simple is to use disk utility , to format your 4 GB USB in Fat 32 ( if you use windows and / Or Linux OS )  . 
Then, use **Unetbootin** on your OS and add bootable flash drive  when you load yours files . 
Wait the end , and you can use your bootable disk / USB drive everywhere.